# Migrate from GDATA calendar resource to Google Calendar Resource api

Tags: google-admin-sdk

One of our projects used GDATA API and we heard that this will be sunset on January 2017. I would like to know if there's an update available to migrate from GDATA to calendar resource api for python?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [Calendar Resource API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars) is part of the Directory API and is one of the new style Google APIs rather than the old GData (Atom based) APIs.

There's no migration guide but you can follow the [Directory API Quickstart guide for python](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python) which takes you through downloading and using the google-api-python-client client library to access and use the Directory API.

Comment: How would you find the unique ID for the customer's Google account?

Comment: To find the unique ID for the customer's Google account see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316835/how-can-i-retrieve-the-customerid-from-a-using-google-api-calls-from-a-nonadmin If you're always working on a particular instance, get it once and write it down. It doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks! 
Lastly, I noticed on developers console there's an update in client email credentials when generating a service account credentials unlike before.

"client_email": "app-name-dev-1@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"

Comment: I don't know or understand what you mean but best to ask it in a question here so you get the right exposure and response.